# Submit all dropdown data fields from different containers & checkout date using button, to SharePoint

Tags: dropdown, patching

I have 4 drop down lists, one text input field, a peoplesearch drop down and two date selectors one for check in and check out. I would like to submit all data in each field to a Sharepoint list I have already created that will show us the loaner laptop that was checked out, by who, and when.
There are 4 fields in each container and I need all the data to go to their corresponding field in SharePoint once I choose submit.